# is it ok to persuade my cat to sleep off my bed (not on)

Tags: cats

My cat has five sleep areas of her own that she uses; all of them designed to be comfy. She uses them all, but she likes to use my bed (a double bed) too. I really do not like to disturb her when she is sleeping on my bed, but have no choice sometimes.

When I turn in for the night, I have tried saying to her, several times "catsname sleep, mummy sleep" in the hopes that she will stay on the bed with me.  She dithers, and even stayed for a little bit once, but decided to jump off the bed.

As well as her other sleep areas, she has a donut bed in the bedroom which she uses from time to time. She likes to use all of her sleep areas.

Is she half-expecting to be disturbed when sleeping on my bed? I just hate disturbing her sleep. We live alone in a one bedroom flat.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Remember last Saturday morning when you just wanted to sleep in but kitty kept jumping on your chest begging to be fed?  This is your opportunity for pay back!  ---  Seriously though, don't worry about it.  If the cat is in your way when you go to bed, gently move her to the floor.  She'll figure it out quick enough.

Comment: The "title" and the description don't seem to be asking the same question. Yes, if is OK to try to set a "no cats in bed" rule, though it will be tremendously easier to explain to the cat if you declare the bed a no-cats surface at all times. It's also OK to trust that the cats will decide for themselves if you're too restless a sleeper for their taste. It"s also OK to push a cat out if the way when they are in a spot you want; they will find someplace else to settle.

Comment: @cobaltduck Also, "cat naps" derive from the fact that cats sleep about 16 hours a day(!) in smallish increments. I don't think the cat is actually disturbed.

Answer (score 1):

In the title of your question you seem to ask if it is ok to have your cat not sleep on your bed. In your question, you seem to want your cat to sleep with you on your bed, so I will address that with a solution that has worked for me.

If your cat is food motivated (only some cats are), she will do anything for a snack. If this is so, you can store cat snacks close to your bed in a cat proof container and after getting into bed place one cat snack next to you on the covers. Your cat will jump up and eat the snack.

I use a container like the one below; note the latching flip-top lid. This container is pretty darned cat-proof; my cat has tried without success for months to break into it.

[image: Cat-proof plastic container]

If you give your cat food once or twice each time you get into bed, eventually she will expect she might get food whenever you go to bed and jump up on your bed once you get in. She will then wait for food, and often fall asleep while waiting. Hey presto! A sleeping cat on your bed.

Comment: True Mark! Exactly cat behavior, though I can tell you, if that treat container was outside of a closed cupboard or drawer, my cat would knock it over and bat it around all night.

Comment: @M.Mat Some cats figure out that futile effort beyond a certain level is pointless, while others may think even the smallest chance of more food is worth attempting. Of course, since I tend to use psychological judo on my cat, if she spent all her time trying to break into an un-openable container like this I would probably place it in my living room during the day just to amuse myself watching her antics and to give her more exercise, and put another in a location in my bedroom she couldn't easily reach. I find direct opposition to a cat is not effective, but sideways thinking often is.